# How to transfer eBooks from an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ebooks

My daughter reads a lovely ebook on her iPhone. I wonder if it is possible to transfer this ebook to my laptop so I can read the ebook as well.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What operating system is on your laptop?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: what application on the iphone manages the ebooks? or is this via Nook or is the book its own application on the iphone?

Comment: She downloaded the book from the store so I would guess it is not a standalone app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calibre.

> Calibre is meant to be a complete e-library solution. It includes
> library management, format conversion, news feeds to e-book conversion
> as well as e-book reader sync features.<sup>1</sup>

[Click here to download](http://calibre-ebook.com/download) from their homepage,  or install from USC

[image]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:USC</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I cant access the ebook on the iphone using Calibre. Can you give me a step direction?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't used Calibre, and don't have an iPhone.  But check out the [calibre User Manual](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/)

Comment: Iphone is not even mentioned in the manual

Comment: Take a look at this (http://www.linuxbuzz.net/2010/06/convert-a-pdf-ebook-to-epub-format-for-your-ipad-iphone-or-ereader/)

Comment: I get the feeling you missunderstand my question. What I want to do is to copy the via istore downloaded book onto my laptop. It is not about converting formats.

Comment: Have you installed Calibre?